# Eclipse content assist not completing android activity methods

Tags: android, eclipse, content-assist

I read many posts about content assist by my problem is special. Content assist works well in many cases, but when I start writing a `method` like below image does not complete it.

[image: no Default proposals] When I start writing a `method` without, for example, `Protected void` like below image and select that method, content assist autocomplete anything.

[image]
completed code by content assist:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Don't say it is normal because I saw my teacher starts with `Protected void` and content assist completed it.

Comment: I just type in "this" then later I delete this.  Good Luck.  BTW You should try android studio it has a better type assist as it picks up all typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio Ctrl + O to override and you select the method to override and presto bang  AS fills in the method including a call through the super object.

Comment: I know that.  My eclipse also doesn't always get the type assist correct I just live with it.  I also relize that you are in a class and it's probably required to use eclips.  Just type in this. and later delete this.  Live with it and get through the class.